# ¿Cómo hacer que cada pedazo de código en r markdown se ejecute correctamente sin tener que llamar mi dataframe en cada pedazo?

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown

Estoy elaborando una presentación en **R markdown** y quisiera que al ejecutar cada fragmento de código no tenga que llamar el dataframe que empleo en cada fragmento. Me explico:

Primero, en mi documento de R markdown llamo mi dataframe

````
```{r, include =FALSE}
library(readxl)
datos_def<- read_excel("datos_def_excel")
summary(datos_def)
````

Ahora, escribo una introducción y añado otro fragmento de código:

````
```{r, eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE}
options(digits=3,scipen=999)
summary(datos_def$edad)
````

Cuando vaya a generar el documento pdf (pincho en Knit) lo hará sin problema. Pero cuando le doy al símbolo de play en color verde para **ejecutar cada fragmento por separado**, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error in summary(datos_def$edad) : 
>     objeto 'datos_def' no encontrado

¿Qué debo hacer para poder ejecutar cada fragmento de código sin tener que llamar en cada fragmento el dataframe `datos_def`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la generación por medio de `knitr` se instancia una sesión de R totalmente nueva e independiente de la que estás usando, dónde obviamente, se procesa el `Rmd` de forma secuencial, y entonces sí, `datos_def` existe por que en primer lugar ya se evaluo la lectura desde el archivo Excel.

En tu sesión interactiva dónde ejecutas cada "chunk" por separado, deberías respetar este mismo orden, es decir, ejecutar en primer lugar, la lectura del archivo, entonces  el objeto  `datos_def` quedará instanciado en el entorno  actual, y el siguiente "chunk" que hace referencia a dicho objeto no te debería dar error.